# coin toss game with know intitial resources on each side

Tags: probability-theory

This question relates to the end game in poker when there only two players left. Suppose player A has 5 times as many chips as player B.  If player A bets the max amount on each hand, the max being the amount the other player has remaining, what is the probability that A will win?  If I could write code I would to solve this problem. My alternative is to do a tedious monte carlo simulation.  Thanks in advance.

Instead of poker, use the coin toss model.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
In the coin toss model, the probability that $A$ wins each hand=$0.5$. For $A$ to win the game, $A$ has to win the first game (or else he's bankrupt), and then he has "balance" his loss and wins so as to stay afloat, and eventually make $B$ bankrupt. Now, the actual calculations are a bit tedious, and the best way to do them is to use the [Reflection Principle.](http://www.math.unl.edu/~sdunbar1/ProbabilityTheory/Lessons/BernoulliTrials/BallotTheorem/ballottheorem.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Real poker is a lot more complicated than this, because different hands have different probabilities to win and players have the option to fold and give up their blinds (at least in most modern poker games). However, if you assume A will always bet the maximum amount and B will always accept, then A has a 50/50 chance of winning the first hand and winning overall, otherwise the stacks will oscillate between 4-2 and 2-4 until someone wins. So the chance A wins is $0.5$ plus $0.5$ times the probability that you will reach +1 before -2 assuming you start at 0 and keep adding either +1 or -1 at each round with equal 0.5 probability. As mentioned in another answer, the reflection principle can often help in calculations like this.

If you want a direct computation for the probability that A wins assuming A lost the first hand and now the stacks are 4-2, then take the hands two hands at a time. The probability that A wins is 0.5, by winning the first hand. The probability that A loses is 0.25, by losing both hands. The probability that you reach the same situation is 0.25, by A losing the first hand and winning the second hand.

So your overall answer is $0.5 + 0.5 \sum_{n=0}^\infty 0.5 \cdot (0.25)^n$